# Visual Studio Installer Projects extension don't overwrite appname.exe.config

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-installer

I use the Installer Projects extension for visual studio 2015 to distribute my sw written in WPF. 
If in the PC is already installed a version of the SW the file appname.exe.config is not overwritten with the new version.
If the PC is not installed the SW is copied to the sw directory the correct version of the fileappname.exe.config.

How can I fix?

Comment: The default rule is that Windows Installer will not overwrite data files that have been updated since the initial install because that destroys user data in the file. Is this likely to be the reason?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Do you know if you can force overwrite? The old configuration file does not contain references to my new web service SOAP

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is often to install the data at first install and then update it with new settings during later upgrades, and that can be in the application itself or the install, and it helps to have some kind of version info in the file. As an example, people don't replace a database full of data just because they have extra table information - they update the existing one.

If you do this during the upgrade, you can condition the custom action on PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED which is set when an upgrade is detected.

Other tools would let you delete the file before upgrade, but Visual Setups don't.

Another possibility: When your app runs, it could always alter the timestamps on the file (probably when it exits) so that creation date and modify date are identical, so that the file appears to be unmodified and will be overwritten.